# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to customize embedded spring-boot tomcat, I created customizer class as shown here

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:configure_springboot.properties")
public class EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration {

  private static final String HTTP_PROTOCOL = "HTTP/1.1";

  private static final String URI_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

  @Value("${server.connection-timeout}")
  int serverConnectionTimeout;


  @Value("${tomcat.http.port}")
  int httpPort;

  @Bean
  public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
    return container -> container.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHTTPConnector());
  }


  private Connector getHTTPConnector() {
    Connector httpConnector = new Connector(HTTP_PROTOCOL);
    httpConnector.setPort(httpPort);
    ((AbstractProtocol) httpConnector.getProtocolHandler()).setConnectionTimeout(serverConnectionTimeout);
    httpConnector.setURIEncoding(URI_ENCODING);
    return httpConnector;
  }

}
```

To test my customization i am creating TomcatServletWebServerFactory here

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration.class, ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class })
public class EmbeddedTomcatConfigurationTest {

  @Autowired
  TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory;

  @Test
  public void tomcatHttpConnector() {
    assertNotNull(tomcatServletWebServerFactory);

  }

}
```

but my test is failing with error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.springboot.configure.EmbeddedTomcatConfigurationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have been trying this from the last three days, can someone guide me what am I missing here?

Comment: ofcourse it will fail. You are running a basic test which won't bootstrap anything. If you want to test you need an `@SpringBootTest` which will bootstrap your application. When doing so remove the `@ContextConfiguration`  as your default application will be started.

Comment: I have tried  with ``@SpringBootTest`` without ``@ContextConfiguration`` but it fails with ```  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test ``` 
even i passed classes to @SpringBootTest (classes) but still it did not work.

Comment: You do have a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class?

Comment: @M.Deinum  No, I created this class in a separate maven module that I have for configuration customizations.

Comment: Then trying to test it is not going to work, at least not like this. You would need to mimic bootstrapping Spring Boot and do a test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally annotated the controller twice:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyController.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

plus

```
@Autowired
private MyController myController;
```

Fixed it by removing `classes = {MyController.class}`